# Is there a way to obtain $A^+$ if we know $A$ and $P=AA^+$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

Suppose you could obtain $P:=AA^+\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ experimentally, where $A^+$ is the Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse. Is there a way to obtain $A^+$?

We know that rank$(A)=N-1$.

Comment: I should add that $A$ is known, but $A^+$ is only known to us via computation and not in a closed form solution. I am interested whether a formula for $A^+$ exists.